# Using decoded JSON in SwiftUI

Tags: json, swift, swiftui

I have just started with Swift so please excuse if this is just a stupid question. I am working on my first App which should load a JSON from the web, parses and displays its content to a LazyVGrid. I have started with the apple tutorial which uses a local JSON and everything worked fine.

Now I have changed to the original nested JSON and URL and I can see the output on the console, but I simply do not know how to use it in my LazyVGrid now. I did a lot of research but all good tutorials end with the successful parsing. I ended up with:

```
    func fetchData()
{
    let url = URL(string: "https://myjsonurl")!
    
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(json, response, error) in
        guard let json = json else {
            return
        }
        
        let welcome = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Welcome.self, from: json)
        print(welcome)
        
        print(welcome.data.data.results[0].title)
    }.resume()
}
```

So as mentioned print() gives me the whole JSON or even specific values like the title. But how can I loop this to my LazyVGrid now?(Xcode is complaining that can not reach it or it is not identifiable because ID is only all the way down in the nested array structure...)

Do I have to create a new array first because the welcome thing is not available outside the fetchData() function? How should it look like to keep the whole JSON structure? I guess all of my experiments have been far too complicated.

I would highly appreciate if someone could give me a hint or an example.

Just in case you need the structure:

```
// MARK: - Welcome
struct Welcome: Codable {
    var data: WelcomeData
}

// MARK: - WelcomeData
struct WelcomeData: Codable {
    var success: Bool
    var data: DataData
}

// MARK: - DataData
struct DataData: Codable {
    var results: [Result]
}

// MARK: - Result
struct Result: Codable {
    var id, title, alias, introtext: String
    var fulltext, publishUp: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, title, alias, introtext, fulltext
        case publishUp = "publish_up"
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear where the `fetchData` happens, and there's no code here at all that relates to SwiftUI. But presumably it's a method in some kind of object. Make it an `ObservableObject` with a `@Published var welcome: Welcome` property, and set that property inside `fetchData`. Then you can use that object as a view model with `@StateObject`, for example.

Comment: `fetchData` is performed within `onAppear` of my view. I have now tried to move `print(welcome.data.data.results[0].title)` by using `public var loans = [Result]()
loans = welcome.data.data.results
print(loans[0].title)` but the result is still I can see everything on console during fetchData but nothing in my view. `Text(loans[0].title)` now says "index out of range..."